# Comment traduire « chip on the shoulder » ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, expressions

Existe-t-il une expression en français équivalente à « *chip on the shoulder* » qui désigne l'attitude d'une personne aigrie qui s’énerve facilement.

Comment: http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=1172085
Une question similaire.

Comment: Not directly related to the question but it seems important to [note](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/chip_on_one%27s_shoulder) that usage has seemingly changed over time with this expression.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Je ne crois pas qu'il y ait une expression française passe-partout pour rendre cette expression anglaise. Elle se traduira différemment selon les contextes. Comme il a déjà été mentionné, on peut penser à *être rancunier* ou *aigri*, mais également à :

- En vouloir à tout le monde
- Avoir du ressentiment

Encore une fois, selon le contexte, pourraient convenir :

- Avoir un esprit querelleur
- Être un éternel mécontent

Au Québec, l'expression colorée *avoir une crotte sur le cœur* existe également.

Answer (score 4):

L'expression *chip on the shoulder* désigne un état de rancœur qui peut mener facilement à l'agressivité.

Je traduirais par *rancunier*, ou peut-être même mieux par *irascible*, c'est à dire prompt à se mettre en colère.

Il y a quelque chose de plus qu'*aigri* ou *susceptible*, selon moi, qui vient de la rancœur qui définit *to have a chip on the shoulder*, l'histoire ancienne sous-entendue. A ma connaissance, on ne peut avoir de *chip on one's shoulder* sans cette histoire ancienne, cette raison (irrationnelle) de s'emporter.

Answer (score 2):

Être soupe au lait.

*Se dit d'une personne particulièrement susceptible et qui s'emporte rapidement.* http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/soupe_au_lait

Dans "Victoria", des Kinks

```
Australia, the chance of a lifetime 
Australia, you get what you work for
Nobody has to be any better than what they want to be 
Australia, no class distinction 
Australia, no drug addiction 
Nobody's got a chip on their shoulder
```

Answer (score 2):

D'après [Wikipédia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chip_on_shoulder) :

> The phrase *having a **chip on one's shoulder** refers to holding a grudge or grievance that readily provokes disputation*.

Tel que je perçois cette explication, il s'agit d'un comportement bagarreur lié à une rancœur. L'exemple fourni [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Chip+on+his+Shoulder) est intéressant également :

> Person 1: "I was raised in a working class family with no luxuries"
>   Person 2: "But now you're a millionaire..."
>   Person 3: "Don't worry about him mate, he's just got a chip on his shoulder."

Il est difficile de vraiment faire ressortir cette idée complète dans une expression courte. *Aigri* et *rancunier* donnent une vague idée dans le cas d'une rancœur, mais cela semble difficilement applicable dans le cas du dernier exemple.

Les réponses précédentes citent, acceptables selon le contexte, les possibilités suivantes :

- Être rancunier/irascible/aigri
- En vouloir à tout le monde
- Avoir du ressentiment
- Avoir un esprit querelleur
- Être un éternel mécontent
- Québec : avoir une crotte sur le cœur

« **Écorché vif** » pourrait correspondre aux cas d'exemple mais il faut comprendre l'origine de cette sensibilité exacerbée.

Answer (score 1):

There is something that seems out of place in  the translations that have been found  (rancunier, empreint de ressentiment, …) and it is only needed to refer to the definition of this expression in the [OALD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/chip_1#chip_idmg_2) to make that out.

The idiomatic expression reckoned with in this source is "**have a chip on your shoulder (about something)**".

> (OALD) (informal) to be sensitive about something that happened in the past and become easily offended if it is mentioned because you think that you were treated unfairly

This is  confirmed in part by the [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/fr/dictionnaire/anglais/have-a-chip-on-your-shoulder), however there is a flagrant departure from the preceding definition as now the anger is felt all the time.

> to seem angry all the time because you think you have been treated unfairly or feel you are not as good as other people
>   - He's got a chip on his shoulder about not having been to university.

We see that mostly one event in the past is concerned and moreover this event has to be recalled to the person in order for him/her to be subjected to the behaviour "have a chip on one's shoulder" refers to. Therefore, there is no question *necessarily* of a person who should be sour (aigrie) which refers to sourness as a permanent trait of character, nor a person that should be irascible (qui s'énerve facilement) which refers also to a permanent trait in someone's psychological make up.

In the SOED, 1993 ed., the definition is different.

> to be touchy and embittered (from a former US practice of so placing a chip as a challenge to others to knock it off)

It is clear that this is another meaning, albeit related; it is also fairly clear from an examination of Google books that the [less current expression](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=chip+on+your+shoulder%2Cchip+on+the+shoulder%2Cchip+on+his+shoulder%2Cchip+on+her+shoulder&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cchip%20on%20your%20shoulder%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cchip%20on%20the%20shoulder%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cchip%20on%20his%20shoulder%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cchip%20on%20her%20shoulder%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cchip%20on%20your%20shoulder%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cchip%20on%20the%20shoulder%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cchip%20on%20his%20shoulder%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cchip%20on%20her%20shoulder%3B%2Cc0) "*chip on the shoulder*", which is not found in the quoted dictionaries, has a meaning identical to that of "chip on one's shoulder" as defined in the SOED; that is to say that the trait of character is not as strongly associated to an event in the past and if *invariably explained* by such an event or series of events, one considers rather its consequenses (anger, acrimony) as not triggered by reminiscence but as a crystalised trait of character ruling the behaviour in all circumstances or else in certain circumstances not necessarily associated to the event or series of events that gave its shape to that behaviour. I believe then that, according to the OP's description, it is this meaning that has to be retained and that the idea of resentment aimed particularly at something ("ressentiment") and the idea of revenge (rancune) are not central in the use of this expression. It is for this reason that I choose to depart from the apparent idea of a necessary inclusion of these notions in the translation and that I think the word "**hargneux**" more appropriate.

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/hargne)) hargne —  A. État ou mouvement de colère sourde où l'agressivité s'allie à l'acharnement. Ruminer sa hargne.

I considered the word "ombrageux" ("ombrage") as it means in part "touchy" ("susceptible") but I thought that the idea of anger, that it does not carry, was essential and I rejected this option.

Answer (score 0):

Je dirais *aigri* ou *susceptible* mais cette expression est assez difficile à traduire...

Answer (score 0):

Pour moi, c'est *ne pas avoir digéré quelque chose*.

Answer (score 0):

Être aigri + prégnance d'une cause spécifique qui rend aigri : il y a un mot pour ça, c'est le ressentiment.

Answer (score -1):

Un "rancunier aigri" me semble coller.

Answer (score -2):

Je crois que la traduction suivante conviendrait : « Avoir une dent contre quelqu'un ».

Comment: Ce n'est pas du tout le sens de [l'expression anglaise](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/a-chip-on-your-shoulder?q=a+chip+on++your++shoulder), comme dit dans la question « attitude d'une personne aigrie qui s’énerve facilemen ».

Comment: (C'est une nouvelle contributrice,il faut la guider gentiment.) Mais je suis d'accord qu'il faut faire quelques efforts pour fournir une réponse un peu plus étoffée, et surtout, comme à l'école, démontrée.

Comment: @Quidam > On attend encore votre accueil chaleureux et vos efforts pour guider cette nouvelle utilisatrice. Puisque vous semblez trouver la communauté de ce site si peu accueillante, pourquoi ne pas montrer l'exemple au lieu de faire les gros yeux ?

Comment: C'est quoi cette agression? Je vous ai agressé? Je ne trouve pas la communauté de Stackexchange accueillante en générale, pas French en particulier, mais en lisant vos agressions, que vous avez la gentillesse de me signifier ici, je suis en train de changer d'avis. Oh oui, vous êtes un amour, vous êtes charmant, compréhensif, et tellement accueillant !!!

Comment: Mon commentaire était gentil, parce que quand on débute sur Stackechange, on ressent le fonctionnement comme très agressif. Ce n'est pas moi que le dit, mais des cinquantaines de sites internet et de forum, si vous n'étiez pas au courant, alors je vous l'apprend. Je laisse un message sympa pour l'utilisateur, et vous me sautez au visage. Vous êtes un amour effectivement!

Comment: Ce genre de commentaire hyper agressif. Oui, cette communauté mérite bien sa réputation.